# How do I upgrade Ubuntu?

Tags: upgrade

I'm new to Ubuntu and Linux in general and coming from Windows I was wondering how to upgrade Ubuntu from one version to another. A new version is released each six months, right? So let's say I'm now running 13.04. When 13.10 will be released in october, how will I upgrade my system?

Will I have to reinstall my whole Linux, loosing all my programs or is there a way to simply replace 13.04 by 13.10?

Answer (score 0):

this link will help u
http://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop/upgrade

Launch the update manager
Press the Superkey (Windows key) to launch the Dash and search for Update Manager

Check for updates

Click the Check button to check for new updates. If there are any updates to install, use the Install Updates button to install them, press Check again after that first update is complete — then press the Upgrade button.

Answer (score -1):

I would not recommend upgrades, they are too often responsible for strange system problems. The best option is reinstalling ubuntu completely new.

During the installer process your old ubuntu installation will be recognized and you can choose "replace existing installation of ubuntu". This guarantees a completely clean version of ubuntu without any odd problems or errors.

Comment: But then I lose all my programs and configuration. And plus it's kinda annoying to reinstall the whole thing two times a year.

Comment: Providing you haven't made system level changes yourself (messing around in `/etc`, `/usr`, building and installing packages from source, etc), the upgrade process should *just work*. It does of course involve some irritation (interface changes, several hours of downtime, etc). If you don't want to upgrade regularly, you should use one of the long-term support versions (current 12.04, next likely to be 14.04) which are supported for 5 years.

Comment: And if you have made system-level changes yourself, you may still want to upgrade, since reinstalling fresh will require those changs to be made again (if you still want them)! In either case, sometimes upgrading will not work well, but for most people most of the time, upgrading is the best way to get to the next version.

Comment: Seriously, I can't find any reason why my solution was voted down. It IS one of (at least) two solutions out there. I am only trying to share my personal experience with upgrading several versions (different combinations) the last years. This is not ok.